# How to show the value in top of each column bar | Hightcharts | Vue-chartkick | Cube Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts, vue-chartjs, cube.js

I am using Vue chartkick and highcharts for visualize the column chart. I want to show the value in top of the each column bar. Help me to complete it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4Bwc.jpg

Above link is image of my output.

```
<template>
    <column-chart lable="value" :min="0" :refresh="60" height="400px" 
     xtitle="City" :data="series" :library="values"></column-chart>
<template>
```

Below code is my script. I am using Vue.js

```
<script>
   data(){
        return{
            values: {
                borderWidth: 10,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        }
    },
</script>
```

My expectation is like below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QF3s5.jpg

Comment: You've used `highcharts` label yet this issue is not strictly related to it. Highcharts API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.dataLabels

Comment: yeah i know. But how to pass as data labels.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

label="Value"

to your column-chart,

i.e.

```
<column-chart :min="0" :refresh="60" height="400px" xtitle="City" 
:data="series" label="Value"></column-chart>
```

Comment: try replacing "Value" with the property name from your data that you want to show as the label

Comment: Now i made some changes in code. Please look into that.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working here: https://codepen.io/torkelv/pen/abbvLWy

It's basically a hack, but unfortunately there is no easy way to do this.

By using the pluginservice:

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
    beforeRender: function(chart) {
        if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
            chart.pluginTooltips = [];
            chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
                chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function(sector, j) {
                    chart.pluginTooltips.push(new Chart.Tooltip({
                        _chart: chart.chart,
                        _chartInstance: chart,
                        _data: chart.data,
                        _options: chart.options.tooltips,
                        _active: [sector]
                    }, chart));
                });
            }); // turn off normal tooltips 
            chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
        }
    },
    afterDraw: function(chart, easing) {
        if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
            // we don't want the permanent tooltips to animate, so don't do anything till the animation runs atleast once 
            if (!chart.allTooltipsOnce) {
                if (easing !== 1) return;
                chart.allTooltipsOnce = true;
            }
            chart.options.tooltips.enabled = true;
            Chart.helpers.each(chart.pluginTooltips, function(tooltip) {
                tooltip.initialize();
                tooltip.update(); // we don't actually need this since we are not animating tooltips 
                tooltip.pivot();
                tooltip.transition(easing).draw();
            });
            chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Then add `options: { showAllTooltips: true, }` to the chart.

Source: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/1861

Comment: Please see my questions once again. I made some changes on that.